# What is `scipy.i`?

Tags: python, scipy

Out of random keyboard bashing, I ended up noticing that there is a variable in `SciPy` called `i`, which is assigned to the string `'6'`. (May be different on other machines?)

I tried using built-in help functions, but there is nothing assigned to `scipy.i` as it only refers to a string.

I also searched the docs and Google, but nothing came up.

Could it be related to version control, or something similar?
By the way, I'm using Enthought Python on Windows 7 (both 64 bits).

This is far from being a critical question, I'm just curious about it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh, this is cute.  From the scipy `__init__.py`:

```
# Emit a warning if numpy is too old
majver, minver = [float(i) for i in _num.version.version.split('.')[:2]]
```

In Python 2, list comprehensions "leak" their loop variables into the enclosing scope.  And thus:

```
>>> import numpy as _num
>>> _num.version.version
'1.6.2'
>>> _num.version.version.split('.')[:2]
['1', '6']
>>> majver, minver = [float(i) for i in _num.version.version.split('.')[:2]]
>>> i
'6'
```

Comment: Haha! Thanks for the fast reply, I suspected it had something to do with version numbers!